# Constructing an Exception with a backtrace

Tags: ruby

Is there really no constructor for Exception in ruby that takes a backtrace? I want to create an exception with backtrace information, but I don't see a way to do that. Right now I'm doing this:

```
exception = create_error ArgumentError, "There is an error here", caller
```

with the create_error method defined like this, i.e. construct the exception then set the backtrace in 2 steps:

```
  def create_error(error_class, msg, bt)
    e = error_class.new(msg)
    e.set_backtrace(bt)
    e
  end
```

Note, I don't want to 'raise' in this case. Am I missing something?

Comment: It does work. In your example, `exception.backtrace` will print out the backtrace info you supplied.

Comment: Yes, I realize it works as written. My question was if there was a constructor that takes a backtrace or some way to create an exception with a backtrace in one line